# I'm writing a bot and it keeps saying PlayCommand is declared but never used

Tags: discord.js

I've been working on a discord bot for a little while now, and just started to code up the play command for music. I've encountered an issue where it states: 'PlayCommand' is declared but never used. What should I do to fix it?

I've tried moving the line closer to the top and it then declares it, but messes up my other code.

```
const YTDL = require('ytdl-core');
function Play(connection, message)
{
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(YTDL(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
    server.queue.shift();
    server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
        if(server.queue[0])
        {
            Play(connection,message);
        }
        else
        {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
});
//Here
class PlayCommand extends Commando.Command
//Here
{
    constructor(client)
    {
        super(client,{
                name: 'play',
                group: 'music',
                memberName: 'play',
                description: 'Adds a song to the queue',
        });
    }

    async run(message, args)
    {
        if(message.member.voiceChannel)
        {
            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection)
            {
                if(!servers[message.guild.id])
                {
                    servers[message.guild.id] = {queue: []}
                }
                        var server = server [message.guild.id];
                        server.queue.push(args);
                        Play(connection, message);
                    }
            }        
        }
    }
}

module.exports = PlayCommand;
```

I expect it to declare the value is read, as on the other commands it has declared it.

Comment: The message is correct. You declare the `PlayCommand` class, but nothing in your code uses it. What part of that are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: The problem I'm having is that on my other commands, I write them exactly the same, yet on this particular one it doesn't work.

Comment: It can't work if you don't use it. As the message says, and I also pointed out, **you declare the `PlayCommand` class but nothing in your code uses it**. The way to fix it is to actually use the class somewhere. I can't tell you why it's diffrerent than your other code, because I can't see your other code.